# How to hide buy Now button in WooCommerce Simple Auction Page

Tags: woocommerce

hello there i was using this code

```
function sbw_wc_add_buy_now_button_single()
{
    global $product;
    printf( '<button id="sbw_wc-adding-button" type="submit" name="sbw-wc-buy-now" value="%d" class="single_add_to_cart_button buy_now_button button alt">%s</button>', $product->get_ID(), esc_html__( 'Buy Now', 'sbw-wc' ) );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'sbw_wc_add_buy_now_button_single' );



/*** Handle for click on buy now ***/

function sbw_wc_handle_buy_now()
{
    if ( !isset( $_REQUEST['sbw-wc-buy-now'] ) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    WC()->cart->empty_cart();

    $product_id = absint( $_REQUEST['sbw-wc-buy-now'] );
    $quantity = absint( $_REQUEST['quantity'] );

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['variation_id'] ) ) {

        $variation_id = absint( $_REQUEST['variation_id'] );
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, 1, $variation_id );
        

    }else{
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity );
    }

    wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_checkout_url() );
    exit;
}

add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'sbw_wc_handle_buy_now' );

/* Dynamic Button for Simple & Variable Product Closed */

//Show Total Sales on Product Page //
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wp_product_sold_count', 11 );
function wp_product_sold_count() {
global $product;
$total_sold = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'total_sales', true );
if ( $total_sold ) echo '
' . sprintf( __( 'Total Sold: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $total_sold ) . '

';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form_func',0 );
function woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form_func() {

        global $product;
        $id = $product->id;         
        $meta = get_post_meta( $id, 'views_count', TRUE );
        if(empty($meta))
        {
            $result = 0;
        }
        else
        {        
        $result = count(explode(',',$meta)); 
        }       
        echo "<div class='custom-visitor-count-st' style='font-size: 20px;'>";
        echo "<i class='fa fa-eye'></i>";
        echo "<span class='cv-value'>";
        echo $result;
        echo " Views</span></div>";
}
```

now in auction page i was getting two buttons for buy now at given price and another is buy now button how can i get rid off from another button

i tried this code

```
#sbw_wc-adding-button.single_add_to_cart_button {
    display: none;
```

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'remove_buy_now_button');
```

function remove_buy_now_button() {
global $product;

```
// Check if the product is an auction product
if (get_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_auction_product', true) === 'yes') {
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
}
```

}

its not yielding a result i am looking for

Any Help would be appreciated

i was expecting to remove extra buy now button from WooCommerce simple auction page

Answer (score 1):

i was able to rectify the issue with button but now the button i added is not working with theme

```
function add_content_after_addtocart() {
global $product;

// Check if it's not the auction product page
if ( !is_auction_product() ) {
    // get the current post/product ID
    $current_product_id = get_the_ID();

    // get the product based on the ID
    $product = wc_get_product( $current_product_id );

    // get the "Checkout Page" URL
    $checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();

    // run only on simple products
    if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && !is_auction_product() ) {
        echo '<div class="clear-sec"></div>';
        echo '<a href="' . $checkout_url . '?add-to-cart=' . $current_product_id . '" class="buy-now button">Buy Now</a>';
    }
}

} add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_after_addtocart' );

 function is_auction_product() { global $product; return $product->is_type( 'auction' ); }
```